# Automatic date and time doesn't work

Tags: time, date

The automatic date and time feature doesn't work even after enabling it. I have dual boot Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 and every time I switch to windows and comeback to Ubuntu, the time is changed and I need to manually change the time and date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu keeps time in UTC, but Windows does it in the local time, causing conflicts.

**Step 1 :** Login to Ubuntu, do not change the time from settings.
**Step 2:** Run the below in terminal

```
timedatectl set-local-rtc 1 --adjust-system-clock
```

**Step 3 :** The time should have updated with the above step.

**Step 4 :** Reboot in windows, and back in Ubuntu and verify the problem has gone away.

Comment: @RajTiwari, please accept the answer.